# Trying to parse a Word document, receiving COM exceptions

Tags: c#, custom-properties, dsofile

This is my code to read custom properties from a file. This works on all file types. but shows `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):`

on word document 2013

> Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

on word document 2003

> (0x80030005): Access Denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030005 (STG_E_ACCESSDENIED))

Also is the `DeleteCustomPropertyThroughDSO` function is correct or not? I am using DSOFile.dll x86 version.

```
private static JObject ReadCustomPropertiesThroughDSO(string fileName)
    {
        JObject Properties = new JObject();
        OleDocumentProperties file = new OleDocumentProperties();
        try
        {
            file.Open(fileName, false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
            foreach (CustomProperty p in file.CustomProperties)
            {
                Properties.Add(p.Name, p.get_Value().ToString());
            }
            file.Save();
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in --> ReadCustomPropertiesThroughDSO: " + ex);
            return null;
        }
        return Properties;
    }

private static string DeleteCustomPropertiesThroughDSO(string fileName)
    {
        OleDocumentProperties file = new OleDocumentProperties();
        try
        {
            file.Open(fileName, false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
            foreach (CustomProperty p in file.CustomProperties)
            {
                p.Remove();
            }
            file.Save();
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write_Log("Exception in -->  DeleteCustomPropertiesThroughDSO: " + ex);
            return FAILURE;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I will be happy if you direct me in a correct direction. Thank you in advance.
My Question is, DSOFile.dll works for xlsx and pptx. The problem is only for Word documents.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Word.Application` COM object?

Comment: No, i am using this in .net framework 2.0. Why should i use Word.Application com object? can u elaborate?

Comment: It's an alternative way to manipulate a Word document.  .NET Framework 2.0?  Are you developing for Windows '98?

Comment: I m testing for Office 2003. So i thought of testing it in .net framework 2.0

Comment: is it good practice to be concerned about .Net framework 2.0 ?

Comment: .NET Framework came out 2002 and was superseded by 3.0 in 2006. To compare how *old* that is, I wanted to look up the iPhone version you had back then... turns out the first iPhone came out in 2007. You might as well support stone tablets.

Comment: i want to add custom property to a Word 2003 document. Assuming that if a person having word 2003 and not any .net framework version installed. I want to read/write a custom property. What might be the possible way to approach?